# Broken links in a Drupal subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, drupal-7, subdomain

Currently I have a site, `https://mysite.com/` a working `Drupal7` site. I want to have something like this, `https://mysite.com/dev` in order for me to test the things first on this location before finally uploading it to the main site. What I did was copy the entire folder where all the files located and pasted it inside `/dev`. I made a duplicate of the DB being used by the main site and edited the file `settings.php` under `sites/default/`, edited the base url from `https://www.mysite.com/` to `https://www.mysite.com/dev`. But when I tried navigating the pages using the links(menu, admin) it gives me `Page not found` response. In addition, I did uncomment this line `RewriteBase /` on my `.htaccess` file. I can also log in, but after logging in the links point to the main site like this, `https://mysite.com/link1`, `https://mysite.com/link2` and so on. What did I miss? Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally got it working. I did mention I edited a single line on my `.htaccess` file which is the `RewriteBase /` and I did, I promise. I changed it to `RewriteBase /dev` but when I tested the site, the links still go to the main site as I have mentioned above. What I did was research more on editing `.htaccess` and somewhere down the road I got [here](https://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site). I lack a few lines of codes which will solve my dilemma, somewhere between `RewriteCond` and `RewriteBase` lines. I need to add these lines, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dev
RewriteRule ^ dev/index.php [L]`. After adding these two lines, I tested the site again and it worked like magic. That's it. Thank you guys.